# How to add another input in the autocomplete form

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, algolia

I have my autocomplete component as below. I see it creates a form and I'm wondering how I could add another input in the form so as to use the user's additional query to point them to resources. I'm trying to achieve something like this autocomplete on the https://www.trulia.com/ home page. Can someone please assist me with how to achieve such? Thanks

````
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <h1>Vue Application</h1>
    <div id="autocomplete" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="jsx">
import { h, Fragment, render, onMounted } from "vue";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import { autocomplete, getAlgoliaResults } from "@algolia/autocomplete-js";
import "@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic";

export default {
  name: "AutoComplete",
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      autocomplete({
        container: "#autocomplete",
        getSources({ query }) {
          return [
            {
              sourceId: "properties",
              getItems({query}) {
                return getAlgoliaResults({
                  searchClient: algoliasearch(
                    "5ALV3LSLJ1",
                    "bde35d15e4037209a089a5731721c6c1"
                  ),
                  queries: [
                    {
                      indexName: "properties",
                      query,
                      params: {
                        hitsPerPage: 5,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                });
              },
      templates: {
                item({ item, components }) {
                  return (
                    <div className="aa-ItemWrapper">
                      <div className="aa-ItemContent">
                        <div className="aa-ItemContentBody">
                          <div className="aa-ItemContentTitle">
                            <components.Highlight hit={item} attribute="location" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                },
              },
          
            },
          ];
        },
        renderer: { createElement: h, Fragment, render },
      });
    });
  },
};
</script> ```
````